# How to change row color in Jtable using UIManager

Tags: java, swing, jtable, uimanager

I tried using UIManager to change border color of the focused cell in my JTable, and it works fine.
But I don't know how to change the color of rows in my JTable using UIManager.
Can anybody tell me what can I write inside UIManager.put(); to change the color of rows.

Here's the code

```
public class JTableExample 
{    
    JFrame f;  
    JPanel p2;

    JTableExample()
    {    
    f=new JFrame();  
    
    p2=new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    p2.setBackground(Color.white);
    p2.setBounds(0, 40, 946, 561);
    
    String data[][]={ {"0","Raj","67"},    
                          {"1","Pranav","78"},    
                          {"2","Saurabh","70"}};  
  
    String column[]={"ID","NAME","Percentage"};   
      
    JTable jt=new JTable(data,column);    
    UIManager.put("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder",new BorderUIResource(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red)));
    JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(jt);  
    
    p2.add(sp);  
    
    f.setBounds(170, 100, 1250, 600);    
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.add(p2);
    
    }     
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        new JTableExample();    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anybody tell me what can I write inside UIManager.put(); to change the color of rows.

Generally you would change  the properties of the `JTable`:

```
table.setBackground(...);
table.setSelectionBackground(...);
```

If you really want to try to change the defaults for all JTables in your application then check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). It provides a list of properties that can be changed for each Swing component.

Comment: how can I change color of selective rowsand the color of top column

Comment: If that was your real question, then why wasn't that originally stated in the question? See: [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/)

Comment: that wasnt my original question, It just came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIManager.put("Table.selectionBackground", Color.PINK);
```